# remove all words from a character vector that are NOT certain words

Tags: r, character, text-mining

I have a character list that looks like this

```
[70] "CSF  5896-6133"                                                           
[71] "CRT  16"                                                                  
[72] "SEEF  54-55"                                                              
[73] "CIF  190-195"                                                             
[74] "DE & /ON CIF  196-222"                                                    
[75] " CRT  17 "                                                                
[76] " SEEF  56-57"                                                             
[77] "DE & /ON CSF  6134-6725 "                                                 
[78] " SEEF  58-60"                                                             
[79] "CRT 18"                                                                   
[80] " CSF 6726-6837"                                                           
[81] "SEEF 61"                                                                  
[82] " CSF 6840-6926"                                                           
[83] " CIF 223-226"                                                             
[84] "SEEF 62-63"                                                               
[85] " CSF 6927-7065"                                                           
[86] " CIF 226-228"                                                             
[87] "CSF 7066-7185"                                                            
[88] "CSF 7186-7311"                                                            
[89] " CIF 229"                                                                 
[90] " SEEF 66"                                                                 
[91] "CSF 7312-7561"                                                            
[92] " CRT 19"                                                                  
[93] " SEEF 67-68"                                                              
[94] "Final data QAQC done on CSF  1-7561"                                      
[95] " CIF  1-229"                                                              
[96] " SEEF  1-68 "                                                             
[97] " CRT  1-19"                                                               
[98] "082015-HOBA-G17-1 changed to offPlot based on GIS review of searched     area"
```

As you can see this is only part of it.

I want to remove all words that are NOT either a number or

```
CSF, CIF, SEEF, CRT
```

So that for example the section from 94-98 would look like

```
[94] "CSF  1-7561"                                      
[95] " CIF  1-229"                                                              
[96] " SEEF  1-68 "                                                             
[97] " CRT  1-19"
```

As you can see line 98 would be deleted completely because it had none of the keywords I wanted it to have. Line 94 also got stripped of some words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following vector:

```
v <- c("Final data QAQC done on CSF  1-7561", 
       "CIF  1-229", 
       "SEEF  1-68", 
       "CRT  1-19",
       "082015-HOBA-G17-1 changed to offPlot based on GIS review of searched     area")
```

You could do:

```
## vector with words to match
cond <- c("CSF", "CIF", "SEEF", "CRT")
## regex that captures digits and tolerates dashes (-) 
reg  <- "(\\d+-?)+$"
## pattern to match either words or regex 
pattern <- paste(c(cond, reg), collapse = "|")
```

Then use `stri_extract_all()` from the `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(v, pattern)
```

Which gives:

```
#[[1]]
#[1] "CSF"    "1-7561"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "CIF"   "1-229"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "SEEF" "1-68"
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "CRT"  "1-19"
#
#[[5]]
#[1] NA
```

---

As per mentionned by @akrun, you could also do:

```
regmatches(v, gregexpr(pattern, v))
```

Which gives:

```
#[[1]]
#[1] "CSF"    "1-7561"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "CIF"   "1-229"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "SEEF" "1-68"
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "CRT"  "1-19"
#
#[[5]]
#character(0)
```

Comment: A base R option is `regmatches(v, gregexpr(pattern, v))`.  Plus one

Answer (score 1):

Use `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
testString <- c("Final data QAQC done on CSF  1-7561" ,
                " CIF  1-229" ,
                " SEEF  1-68 ",
                " CRT  1-19",
                "082015-HOBA-G17-1 changed to offPlot based on GIS review of searched     area" )

str_extract(testString, "(CSF|CIF|SEEF|CRT)\\s+\\d+-\\d+")
[1] "CSF  1-7561" "CIF  1-229"  "SEEF  1-68"  "CRT  1-19"   NA
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer I posted 5 mins ago ;)

Comment: I admit it's very similar. Just try out a slightly different regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `stringr` library.

Here's a subset of your data.

```
x <- c("CSF  5896-6133",                                                           
"CRT  16",                                                                  
"SEEF  54-55",                                                              
"CIF  190-195",
"Final data QAQC done on CSF  1-7561",
"082015-HOBA-G17-1 changed to offPlot based on GIS review of searched     area"
)
```

You could use `str_extract` and a regular expression matching your pattern.

```
library(stringr)

> str_extract(x, '(CSF|CIF|SEEF|CRT)[:space:]+([0-9]|-)+')
[1] "CSF  5896-6133" "CRT  16"        "SEEF  54-55"    "CIF  190-195"   "CSF  1-7561"   
[6] NA
```

When you have nothing matching the pattern it will return a missing value.

Comment: Isn't this the same as @Psidom ?

Comment: Yeah - it's pretty similar! I posted it only slightly before his response

Comment: Actually he posted at 16:54:18 and you at 16:54:44 ;) Anyways it's a slightly different regex as well so OP can experiment with all solutions. Cheers !